# ADF V2 - set parameter value from filepath of the blob (csv)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm building a solution with ADF V2 which need to import data from CSV files into Azure SQL Data Warehouse. I want to use new Azure Blob Storage trigger (event trigger) to execute pipeline every time new CSV file is added to blob container. CSV files are organized in the following hierarchy (container and virtual folders):

- FactoryId (1, 2, 3, ..)
- --Year (2017, 2018, ...)
- ----Month (01, 02, ...)
- -------Day (01, 02, ... 30)

I want to set ADF variable with name FactoryId from the FilePath of the blob that has raised the event trigger (ex. /1/2018/06/25  - FactoryId would be 1). Then I would like to use this value as input value for a column in a table in Azure SQL DWH. The table will have same columns like in the CSV file plus this one FactoryId and I want to populate this value from variable / filepath value.

Is this possible with ADF V2 and if not what would be your other suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- For blob event trigger,

When a blob events trigger fires, it makes two variables available to your pipeline: folderPath and fileName. To access these variables, use the @triggerBody().fileName or @triggerBody().folderPath expressions.

Please reference [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger#using-blob-events-trigger-properties).

- For Then I would like to use this value as input value for a column in a table in Azure SQL DWH.

Currently, there is no easy way to implement this directly. You may use [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity).